# Wrong origins when adding subviews programmatically to UIView using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have a `UIView` subclass where I programmatically create and add some subviews. To be exact, I have 6 subviews aligned horizontally next to each other with zero space between them. The side margins (i.e. the distance from the left border of my view to the first subview and the distance from the last subview to the right border of my view) must be 16pt and the remaining space must be distributed equally among the subviews. It should look like this:

[image]

I am trying to accomplish this using autolayout like this:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"digit1":digit1, @"digit2":digit2, @"digit3":digit3, @"digit4":digit4, @"digit5":digit5, @"digit6":digit6};
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[digit1][digit2(==digit1)][digit3(==digit1)][digit4(==digit1)][digit5(==digit1)][digit6(==digit1)]-16-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
```

When I run this on iPhone 5 with 320pt screen view I expect the following result:

Subview width: (320 - 2*16) / 6 = **48**

So the frames should be:

```
digit1: x =  16, width = 48
digit2: x =  64, width = 48
digit3: x = 112, width = 48
digit4: x = 160, width = 48
digit5: x = 208, width = 48
digit6: x = 256, width = 48
```

However, at runtime a strange thing happens: my margins are wrong:

[image]

The subview frames I get are these:

```
digit1: x =  21, width = 48
digit2: x =  66, width = 48
digit3: x = 111, width = 48
digit4: x = 156, width = 48
digit5: x = 201, width = 48
digit6: x = 246, width = 48
```

So my left margin is 21pt and the right is 26pt. Also, the subviews overlap by 3pt.

I have inspected the view hierarchy with Reveal and I can confirm that there *is* a constraint for the margins with the correct constant of 16. But the frame is for some reason different. There also don't seem to be any other conflicting constraints, nor do I get an autolayout error when I run the app.

Can anyone see what I am missing here?

**EDIT:**

Testing out Aloks suggestion with using spacer views in stead of spacing constraints I tried this:

```
UIView *spacer1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *spacer2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
spacer1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
spacer2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
spacer1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
spacer2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self addSubview:spacer1];
[self addSubview:spacer2];
NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"spacer1":spacer1, @"digit1":digit1, @"digit2":digit2, @"digit3":digit3, @"digit4":digit4, @"digit5":digit5, @"digit6":digit6, @"spacer2":spacer2};
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[spacer1(16)][digit1][digit2(==digit1)][digit3(==digit1)][digit4(==digit1)][digit5(==digit1)][digit6(==digit1)][spacer2(16)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the spacer views are positioned correctly, but the digit subviews remain where they were.

Comment: after adding constraints call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help, nor did I expected it to. My issue is not that I need the views to be laid out immediately, which is what this method is meant to do. I am perfectly fine with waiting for the autolayout to take effect at a later point. In fact, I believe that my constraints do get activated (at least partially) since the subview width is correct.

Comment: Set in `UIView` subclass `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` and if you added all your autolayout contraints programmatically in UIViewController, some contraints in the Interface Builder may still be enabled. You can make sure that IB contraints are ignored by setting `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

Comment: the remaining space must be distributed equally among the subviews. is it done automatically ?

Comment: @SunilSharma: Unfortunately it didn't help. I was already setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` on the subviews, but now I also tried setting it on the superview as well. Still no change.

Comment: @PKT: No, that is done by setting the widths of the subviews to be equal (to the first subview).

Comment: [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[digit1][digit2(==digit1)][digit3(==digit1)][digit4(==digit1)][digit5(==digit1)][digit6(==digit1)]-16-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

in your code you must set all 4 constraint to digit 2 to digit 5 (LEADING and TRAILING) it will help  autolayout engine to exact calculations

Comment: see the answer of lion

Comment: @pajevic Is it possible for you to share demo project replicating the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved my issue, and the problem was actually elsewhere. I am not the only developer on this project and I hadn't realized (it's a big class) that someone else had been setting the position of the subviews manually in the `layoutSubviews` method, like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // set center for each digit view
}
```

And of course, since the position was set after `[super layoutSubviews]` it changed the positions set by my autolayout constraints.

I want to thank you all who have contributed here. Your solutions helped me confirm that my original solution was in fact correct and forced me to look for the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints should be like :

`equal width` to every views with each other

`fixed height` to every views

`leading,trailing and top or bottom (which is appropriate)` to every view.

And it will work fine

See the output of this constraints

[image]

You just need to convert it in code!!!!

and if you are adding views programmatically then how you are setting view's frame is also matter. Your frame should be dynamic as per screen size.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: The setup you are describing is what I have (or at least what I think I have). The constraints are added programatically with VFL as shown in my answer. I suspect there might be an error there.

Comment: have you set leading,trailing,bottom and fixed height ?

Comment: I am setting top and bottom space to superview to zero. I haven't shown it here since it is not relevant for the my horizontal issues I am having. The leading and trailing constraints are also set as described in my answer and shown in the VFL code.

Comment: I am not much aware of VFL but if i am not wrong i think you have just set leading and trailing to just first and last view with constant 16. you need to set leading and trailing of every view with constant 0

Comment: They are set. In VFL `[view1][view2]` (with nothing between them) is shorthand for `[view1]-0-[view2]`, which is how spacing constraints are created.

Comment: are you sure is it like so? and where is top bottom or height constraints?

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html
They write: **Flush Views** `[maroonView][blueView]`

Comment: I haven't shown the vertical constraints as I don't think they are relevant, but they are created like this for each of the subviews:

`[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[digit]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDict]];`

Comment: You are missing something i think!! If you set constraints like i mentioned in answer, It should work. Because if constraints works from interface builder then it must work programmatically if you set exact same.

Comment: I was missing something. And it was completely unrelated to my layout constraints. You can read about it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have used 16 as `leading` and `trailing`, instead make `spacer1 (UIView *spacer1) and spacer2 (UIView *spacer2)`.

write your `VFL` this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *spacer1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *spacer2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    spacer1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    spacer2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    spacer1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    spacer2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:spacer1];
    [self.view addSubview:spacer2];

    UIView *digit1 = [UIView new];
    digit1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    digit1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit1];

    UIView *digit2 = [UIView new];
    digit2.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    digit2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit2];

    UIView *digit3 = [UIView new];
    digit3.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    digit3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit3];

    UIView *digit4 = [UIView new];
    digit4.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    digit4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit4];

    UIView *digit5 = [UIView new];
    digit5.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    digit5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit5];

    UIView *digit6 = [UIView new];
    digit6.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    digit6.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:digit6];

    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"spacer1":spacer1, @"digit1":digit1, @"digit2":digit2, @"digit3":digit3, @"digit4":digit4, @"digit5":digit5, @"digit6":digit6, @"spacer2":spacer2};
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[spacer1(16)][digit1][digit2(==digit1)][digit3(==digit1)][digit4(==digit1)][digit5(==digit1)][digit6(==digit1)][spacer2(16)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[spacer1(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[spacer2(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit1(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit2(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit3(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit4(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit5(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[digit6(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

}
```

it should work.

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: This didn't work, but it did underline the weird behaviour. See my updated question.

Comment: also even if you don't use spacer just replace spacer with -16-, it will work